# Locked cell moves when adding rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to protect specific cells within a sheet. For example, I3:I5, J7 and K3:K5.  Protecting a cell is easy. The challenge is I need to add new rows to the stop of my spreadsheet each day.  When I add these new rows, the protections move by however many rows I add.  For example, if I add 10 rows, my protections are now: I13:I15, J17 and K13:K15. How do I avoid these protections moving?  I've tried putting in a $ to keep the reference but google sheets strips out dollar signs in protect cells.  Is there a simple way to avoid the issue of protected cells moving?

Thank you,

Dave

Comment: Can you be more specific on where the active cell is when adding rows?  If you add rows to the bottom the protection does not expand for me.  Do you have a sample sheet to look at?

Comment: are you looking for a solution using google app script or are you looking for a manual solution? If yes, then please share the sample of the sheet you're working on.